# How to remove custom post type and add category and post name

Tags: plugins, functions, permalinks

I have a custom post type called ***listing*** and taxonomy for this listing is called ***listing_cat***.

At the moment my wordpress permalinks appear in this format

```
localhost/wordpress/listing/listing_cat/post_name
```

I want to **remove listing** from permalink so it would appear in this format.

```
localhost/wordpress/listing_cat/post_name
```

Problem is when I remove listing from permalink with the help of **"post_type_link"** filter it direct me to 404 Page.

Here is the code that I am using that I have taken from another question.

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'projectcategory_permalink_structure', 10, 4);
function projectcategory_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {
    if (false !== strpos($post_link, 'listing')) {
        $projectscategory_type_term = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'listings_categories');

        if (!empty($projectscategory_type_term)){

           // var_dump($projectscategory_type_term);
            $post_link = str_replace('listing', array_pop($projectscategory_type_term)->
                slug, $post_link);
        } else{

            $post_link = str_replace('listing', 'uncategorized', $post_link);
        }
    }

    return $post_link;
}
```

What is workaround of this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you click on the permalink setting in the WP Admin to refresh the permalinks settings?  You have to refresh that for your code changes to stick.  Go to settings > permalinks > save permalinks